# Can i convert multilingual Excel file to english using bing text translator java api?

Tags: java, apache-poi, bing-translator-api

I am working on my final year project where i am able to convert multilingual text to english using bing java api. I have to convert an excel file to english. THe excel file has multi language content. My query is how to read excel file as apache poi doesn't support language other than english. Please sugggest.

Comment: It's just text though.  Surely whether it's English, French, German or Swahili is irrelevant.

Comment: Apache POI works just fine with all text that can be stored within an Excel file!

Comment: An Excel source doesn't make an Excel relevant question.

Comment: Thanks . I was not able to read multilingual as as txt encoding in eclipse was not utf-8. now its working . Thanks again.